# If B is the set of all upper bounds for A, then B is nonempty, bounded below, and inf B = sup A

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

1.2 Let $A$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ containing at least two points. Prove:

**(a)** $\infty <$ inf $A <$ sup $A < -\infty$

**(b)** If $B$ is a nonempty subset of $A$, then inf $A <$ inf $B <$ sup $B <$ sup $A$

**(c)** If $B$ is the set of all upper bounds for $A$, then $B$ is nonempty, bounded below, and inf $B =$ sup $A$

Proof.

Parts **(a)** and **(b)** are trivial. As for part **(c)**, $B$ being nonempty follows from the fact that $A$ is bounded. Clearly, $B$ is bounded below, otherwise the supremum of A would be $-\infty$ but by definition $A$ is nonempty so we cannot have $B$ to be unbounded below. We can now argue that if inf $B <$ sup $A$, continuity of $\mathbb{R}$ gives an $a\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. inf $B<a<$sup$A$. Clearly $a\in A\cap B$ (Otherwise $a$ would be a lower bound for $A$ and we know for a fact that $a\in B$). Since $a\in A$, $a\le sup A$. Since $a\in B$, $a\ge inf B$. Combining these two inequalities form the desired contradiction. The other "case" $inf B>sup A$ follows in analogous fashion. Hence, $inf B = sup A$

Comment: I would recommend that you *not* post your attempts at solutions of every single problem in the textbook. Learn from the comments you get, work on your own, and then post when you get to a more troublesome exercise and have some specific questions to ask us.

Comment: Alright professor this shall be the last that follows that sequence.

Comment: You can't justify that $a \in A$. What if $A$ has just two points, and $\inf B$ is between them?

Answer (score 3):

For your point **a)** I would suggest you edit your question, as I assume you switched up your $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. We know $\sup A$ is the least upper bound of $A$, and with $A$ being bounded, it will be $\leq$ said upper bound, so $\sup A$ cannot be $+\infty$, and no less can it in this case be less than $-\infty$.

Concerning point **b)** you have written $<$ in each of these inequalities, this is incorrect, as nowhere is it stated that $B \neq A$. One way to look at this, is to view it as separate questions.
First we prove that $\sup B \leq \sup A$. We know that $A$ is bounded and non-empty, so $A$ must contain a supremum. We note that $\sup A$ is an upper bound for $A$ (by definition of the supremum as the least upper bound). As $B \subseteq A$, $\sup A$ will also be an upper bound for $B$. Lastly we note that $\sup B$ is the *least* upper bound for $B$, thus $\sup B \leq sup A$. The other inequalities are trivial after this proof.

Concerning **c)**. You state the following: *"but by definition $A$ is nonempty so we cannot have $B$ to be unbounded below"*, note however that $B$ being bounded follows from $A$ being bounded (solely knowing that $A$ is non-empty is not enough). A shorter way to show the equivalence would be the following. We know that $\sup A \subseteq B$ (as it is *an* upper bound for $A$), then it directly follows that $\inf B \leq \sup A$, by definition of $\inf B$. I'll leave the rest to you.